How to make ListView height dynamic based on content in Flutter?
I am using a ListView.builder to display a horizontal list of images in Flutter. Currently, I have wrapped the ListView in a SizedBox with a fixed height (e.g., height: 100.h). However, I want the height of the ListView to adjust dynamically based on the content height.
SizedBox(
  height: 100.h, // Fixed height causing the issue
  child: ListView.builder(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    itemCount: imageList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      var image = imageList[index];

      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.w),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              child: Image.file(
          File(image.path),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          width: 80,
          height: 80,
        ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
              child: Text(
                image.description ?? "",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.sp, color: Colors.black),
                maxLines: 1,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
),


Why do you need to wrap your ListView with a SizedBox. Can't you just remove the SizedBox?

For this flutter already have a builtin widget IntrinsicHeight.
IntrinsicHeight(
  child: ListView.builder(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    itemCount: imageList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      var image = imageList[index];

      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.w),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // Allow the column to adjust dynamically
          children: [
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              child: Image.file(
                File(image.path),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                width: 80,
                height: 80,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
              child: Text(
                image.description ?? "",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.sp, color: Colors.black),
                maxLines: 1,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
),

you can also adjust the layout using layoutbuilder
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) {
    double maxHeight = 0; // Variable to track the maximum height

    // Calculate the maximum height of the children
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      maxHeight = imageList.fold<double>(
        0,
        (previousValue, image) {
          double childHeight = 80 + 4 + 15.sp; // Image height + padding + text height
          return childHeight > previousValue ? childHeight : previousValue;
        },
      );
    });

    return SizedBox(
      height: maxHeight, // Dynamically set height
      child: ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: imageList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          var image = imageList[index];

          return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.w),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                  child: Image.file(
                    File(image.path),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    width: 80,
                    height: 80,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                  child: Text(
                    image.description ?? "",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.sp, color: Colors.black),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  },
);

first try use IntrinsicHeight it's a professional and easy approach.
